# If I want to apply a filter to an Image should I use the IIR or FIR filters?

Tags: image-processing, fft, discrete-signals, z-transform

So I have discrete pixel values in the image and each row or column would make a signal. I would like to filter some of the rows or columns to remove high frequency components from them. Should I use the Z transform (difference equations) or work with the FFT of the data to perform the filtering?

Answer (score 2):

Some important vocabulary first to get the terminology right:

- [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) - Discrete Fourier Transform. This is a transform. It is quite computationally intensive. ($O(N^2)$).
- [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fft) - This is an *algorithm* that makes computing the [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) very fast. ($O(N \log N)$)
- [Z-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform): This is just a mathematical generalization of the [DTFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) - it is not an algorithm. When $z = e^{jw}$, then we have the [DTFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform). Moreover, the [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) is a (uniform) sampling of the [DTFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform).

So from a practitioner's standpoint, what you will use in your filtering technique is the FFT - at least with a lot of classical techniques. This is because as stated above, the FFT is an algorithm.

In relation to implementing actual difference equation VS doing your filtering via FFT: Most of the time, implementing a convolution is done via the FFT, because of the computational simplicity. There is a point however at which it becomes most efficient to perform a convolution directly, but that is only if your image/signal sizes/lengths are really small.

Comment: Yes, the OP seems confused. I *think* what they are asking is whether they should implement filtering using the FFT or just do the time-domain implementation of the linear, constant-coefficient difference equation.

Comment: @PeterK. Yes, hopefully this will elucidate the taxonomy somewhat so that it can help them massage the question.

Comment: Right sorry, @PeterK. is correct I wanted to ask is it better if I use difference equations to do the filtering or perform some manual multiplicative filtering on the FFTed data.

Comment: @user1084113 See my edit.

Comment: @user4619 I'm sorry I should be more clear, performance is not an issue, say if I was to implement a second order high pass filter through difference equations (bilinear transform of H(z) then use the digital biquad generalization to get y[n]) VS FFT the data and window past a certain frequency (retain all values above a certain frequency and make the rest zero) which of the two approaches would yield better results?

Comment: @user1084113 You are really just asking which filtering method is better, IIR, or FIR, for filtering for images. Please edit the question to ask this.